# How to bypass ID column without being used in the training model but have it as output - Azure ML

Tags: machine-learning, azure-ml, machine-learning-model

The input data in the model includes column ControlNo.

[image]

But I don't want this column being part of learning process so I'm using `Select Columns in Dataset` to exclude `ControlNo` column.

But as a output I want those columns:

```
ControlNo, Score Label, Score Probability
```

So basically I need NOT to include column `ControlNo` into learning process,
but have it as output along with `Score Label` column.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Searh for dropping a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do this, one less elegant than the other:

1. You can drop whatever column you don't want to use and add them together after getting the scores. Though you might need to reorder columns etc.

[image]

Or...

2. There is a block called **Edit Metadata** which can be used to do what you need. Select whatever columns from the column selector you don't want to use and use the option `Fields > Clear Feature` from the block properties. These columns won't be used in the calculations but will be present when you visualise the Score Model output together with the rest of the columns and the scores. Moreover, columns in that output statistics will be labelled as *Feature* type if they were used in the calculations. So you straightaway know which columns were actually used in the calculations or not. Block [help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/edit-metadata) is quite useful here.

[image: Edit Metadata Block]

[image]

Comment: How do you reorder columns in MLS?

Comment: You can use a _Select Columns in Dataset_ block. If you use the option include the column names, there is a tick above that says _Allow duplicates and preserve column order in selection_ that will keep the order of the columns you include.